# I recently installed Ubuntu but I can't get any sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So I recently installed Ubuntu, and there is no audio output with or without headphones plugged in, while playing music in the browser, music streamed from rhythmbox or while playing  music on the hard drive.

Comment: What's the card model?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to unmute alsamixer (this is separate from pulseaudio).  Here is a link to the instructions I will reference along with other instructions in the rare event that this isn't the problem:  http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/ .

Here are the pertinent instructions for unmuting alsamixer:
.
1.  Bring up a terminal using Ctrl-Alt-T
2.  Type in "alsamixer" without the quotes
3.  Select the correct sound card using F6
4.  Move to "Master" with left and right keys
5.  If there is an MM under the bar graph (also check "Headphon" and "Speaker") this will correct the issue.  If not you have another issue entirely.
6.  Press "M" to unmute.
7.  Use up and down arrows to turn up volume to approximately 80
8.  Use right arrow to move one click to "Headphon"
9.  Repeat steps 4, 6 and 7
10. Use right arrow to move one click to "Speaker"
11. Repeat steps 4, 6 and 7
12. Exit from alsamixer with Esc key
13. Close terminal window
14. Play music or video with sound to make sure the problem is rectified.  If needed, adjust volume at appropriate area of screen (the icon will look like a speaker with three curved lines of increasing length in front of it)

From personal experience and research this is more of a problem with Lubuntu than the other Canonical OSes but it can happen with all of them.  It is unknown why alsamixer sometimes installs muted or why Lubuntu is more susceptible to this issue.

Comment: This didn't work, is it possible I'm choosing the wrong sound card?

Comment: It shows two sound cards:

Comment: 0 HD-Audio Generic and 1 HD-Audio Generic

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Reboot your machine and check it.

If still with no sound, try reinstalling `Alsa` and `Pulse audio` :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Then run this command again.

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Reboot your machine and check again.

Comment: This didn't do anything